# What kinds of optimization problems can be solved by greedy algorithms accurately?

Tags: algorithms, optimization

1. I was wondering what kinds of optimization problems can be solved by
   greedy algorithms accurately?
2. I don't understand the following quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm#Types):

   > Greedy algorithms can be characterized as being 'short sighted',
   >   and
   >   as 'non-recoverable'. They are ideal only for problems which have
   >   'optimal substructure'.

   If I am correct, an optimization problem with 'optimal substructure'
   can  accurately be solved by dynamic programming method, not always
   by greedy algorithms. So what does "greedy algorithms are ideal only
   for problems which have 'optimal substructure'" mean?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Have you seen this before? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid#Greedy_algorithms

Answer (score 1):

Optimal substructure means that optimising every part of the structure will give an optimal solution for the whole structure.